# Stack Overflow doesn't display correctly when using Tor Browser

Tags: bug, status-declined

I use Tor browser for nearly all of my internet browsing, including Stack Overflow. This wasn't a problem for me until about a week or two ago, when Stack Overflow produced two different errors when using Tor Browser.

One, it would sometimes display without using any styles. The pages displayed in a linear fashion, and there were no fonts other than Times New Roman, no pictures, and no color, just like in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253120/why-stackoverflows-page-displays-like-this-in-my-browser).

The second problem happens 100% of the time when problem one happens, and sometimes it happens on its own. When I try to log into Stack Overflow, I enter my Stack Exchange account information, hit enter or click login, and nothing happens.

These problems do not happen all of the time, but as I said, when problem one happens, problem two always follows it. I have tried accessing this from multiple machines, using multiple script settings, and the same problem happens. I am also a member of the Tor Stack Exchange, and sometimes, when I am logged into one Stack Exchange, and click over to the other in Tor Browser, the one will display with errors and the other will work perfectly.

I believe this is a bug, but if anyone knows a solution on my end, please tell me. (And please don't just tell me to stop using Tor.)

Comment: Note that there is at least one person trying to (ab)use tor to bypass bans put in place to deal with their *very*  antisocial behaviour, and many tor exit nodes have been IP blocked as a result. You are probably seeing those blocks.

Comment: Aside from what Martijn mentions, Stack Exchange does not support Tor Browser (although what Martijn said is much more likely the cause).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Tor Browser is not [officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need); any breakage in styling and functionality is at your own risk.
- There has been a history of abusive users using Tor to bypass restrictions placed on their accounts. As a result of recent extreme misbehaviour, many Tor exit nodes have been IP blocked. If you cannot connect at all, your request most probably came through such an exit node.

It is unlikely that the Stack Exchange team is going to ease up on these two restrictions.

Comment: Maybe all access from Tor should just be blocked, as there is no good reason for anyone to use it (to access SO) unless they are doing something bad.

Comment: @IanRingrose: I don't subscribe to that view, really. So anyone in North Korea trying to build tech to support freedom of speech will have to do so without Stack Overflow then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure that answers it since I can be, for example, using Stack Overflow just fine in Tor, then click over to Tor Stack Exchange and have both problems. Is it possible that *.stackoverflow.com would be set to allow a certain Tor IP address and *.stackexchange.com be set to block it?

Comment: @AustrianDairyman Yes, that's certainly possible.

Comment: @AustrianDairyman: HTTP is a stateless protocol, so each request you make can come from a *new* Tor exit node, each with their own IP address. Your requests could come from any IP address at any given time, and you are essentially playing Russian Roulette; some of your requests will be blocked, some will succeed.

Comment: @AustrianDairyman: From [this Tor.SE post](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/262/for-how-long-does-a-circuit-stay-alive) I understand that circuits will be reused, but only for up to 10 minutes. So your connections come from one exit node for that length of time, then hop to another exit node. If that exit node is blocked, you cannot connect.

Comment: Even though this answer is probably technically correct I have a hard time up-voting it because I absolutely wish that Tor exit nodes wouldn’t be treated differently from every other IP.

Comment: In further testing (specifically the upgrade in Tor Browser to Firefox ESR 32), I discovered that the "unsupported" feature was the real problem here. I have since gotten better security and use Tor to access SE less often, but when I do I no longer have any problems and am never blocked.