# Can't upload profile picture images

Tags: support, bug, status-declined

Every time I attempt to upload a profile picture to Stack Overflow it ends up showing as a blank tile. I have tried copying the image location directly, and also uploading the image from my home computer, with no success.

Could sometimes fix this or tell me what might be causing it? I'm using the latest version of TOR, with the update that just downloaded.

Comment: Is imgur blocked? Any messages in the Dev Console?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I'll have a look. I have tried with a none-imgur link as well.

Comment: What size is the image?

Comment: Warnings but no errors. Output: "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3:6598
"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys" util.js:211:12
Empty string passed to getElementById()."

Comment: @Oded The image is less than 2 MB. One is 6.19KB... the other... 496KB. Neither work.

Comment: Do note that [tor is not officially supported](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272280/578411) so I doubt it will be fixed.

Comment: @rene Ah, I didn't realise you don't support TOR. It figures I suppose... you like to see who you're dealing with ;).

Comment: Can you screenshot where / when it breaks and upload that to a filesharing service? And where does that util.js come from because I don't seem to have that file?

Comment: @rene I haven't added a util.js myself. I will screengrab and upload now.

Comment: TOR exit nodes are known to be blocked, so you might have working stuff one moment and be completely lost moments later.

Comment: @rene http://tinypic.com/r/15wnv2q/9

Comment: Those images should come from i.stack,imgur.com, can you see other profile pics, mine for example? btw: The warning in util.js about noAPiKeys is repro-ed by me. That is maybe something for @Oded to confirm if that is by-design.

Comment: @rene I can't see your image either. Can you see mine?

Comment: util.js is part of the Google Maps API scripts - that error suggests that the API keys are not passed in, which must be something that TOR browser does. Sorry - but this is not something we will fix, it is not a supported browser.

Comment: Yes, I can, a fox in front of a flowery thing...

Comment: @Oded I'm only on chrome and I do get the util.js as well and I'm not using TOR.and I disabled all my scripts. If it is not yours maybe an ad inserts it?

Comment: @Oded Do you support Firefox if I configure it with proxy settings and no caching... Is there a particular setting I'm not allowed to change which makes TOR unsupported?

Comment: @AmyMcBride - it does a lot of things (one thing is how it can change IP addresses on us - that's not a well supported scenario), proxy and no caching should be fine.

Comment: @rene - util.js should come up fine. But the API errors? Those shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Oded when I visit [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/578411) I get the warning: `Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys` and at the top of the call stack is [`stats.js`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/stats.js) in the `__gjsload__` function but I can't find how, where and when that started.

Comment: @rene - Oh, I see now. Not sure when that happened.

Comment: @Oded do you want me to open a new bug for that?

Comment: @rene - if you want. I've made people aware, so it will get fixed soon one way or another.

Comment: @Oded done [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326649/noapikeys-when-editing-your-user-profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TOR browser is not a supported browser.

Please use one of the [supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) and make sure you can access all of the required resources (listed in the linked article).

Comment: Can I install Tor-Proxy.NET on Firefox?

Comment: @AmyMcBride - sorry, no idea. But - I suspect that if that proxy works similar to how the TOR browser works, it will cause the same kinds of issues.

Comment: Today, I tried uploading a new profile pic with both Chrome, Firefox and Explorer it's not saving. Once I click save, the image turns blank/broken.

Comment: @NoSssweat - looks like a problem with image resizing on the imgur side. When I look at the URL for it (without resizing), I see the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MibYK.jpg, but adding a size parameter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MibYK.jpg?s=128 shows a blank image.

Comment: @NoSssweat - I would add to that - imgur have been having server issues lately: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301832/image-uploads-not-working-imgur-rejecting-request-on-multiple-sites

Comment: It also appears that this issue has been raised recently - @NoSssweat: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301856/sizing-suffixes-on-uploads-broken

Comment: Even with CHROME browser, I am facing this issue! Has nothing to do with TOR. It appeared this month (June 2023) someday and still I am unable to upload a new picture to my profile. Only Identicon works, but I don't want to use that.