# NoApiKeys when editing your user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

While diagnosing an issue with [uploading an profile picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326645/cant-upload-profile-picture-images) the OP mentioned an Google Maps API warning:

> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Assuming it was caused by their specific setup I was a little bit surprised that I could repro that same warning on a plain Google Chrome without any userscripts or plugins running.

I'm not sure why it happens but when the warning is raised the function `__gjsload__` in the file `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/stats.js` is at the top of the call stack.

After a short [exchange of comments with Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326645/cant-upload-profile-picture-images#comment360042_326645) it was reproduced/confirmed.

As it is [being looked at](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326645/cant-upload-profile-picture-images#comment360054_326645) I expect this bug report soon to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) within 6 to 8 ...

Comment: Discussing on this coming Monday's call.

Comment: Is it that bad? I only envisioned that someone would take the keys from Google and deploy them ...

Comment: Nah, just need to discuss how many client keys we need (this api is used both by Q&A and Careers), and what type of keys (standard or premium).